# C++, when I put return 0 in a function and use the function main, the system still keep working

Tags: c++, while-loop, return

My idea is to write a exit function to terminate the whole system, so I wrote the function int exit_c(), and put it in the while loop, but it seems that the system keeps working.

```
int main() {

    while (true) {
        exit_c();
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

```
int exit_c() {
    cout << "close" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: console result]

But when I replace the exit_c() in while loop, which just system("pause") and return 0, the system will terminate.

```
int main() {

    while (true) {
        system("pause");
                return 0;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you asking for the difference between returning from `main` and returning from another function?

Comment: Yes, this is key point I think.

Comment: Returning from `exit_c` is not the same thing as returning from `main`; a function returns to the place where it was called. You should probably read more about functions in your favourite C++ book. (If this worked as you expect, returning from any function at all would terminate the program immediately. This would be worse than useless.)

Comment: you cannot learn c++ by experimenting. This time it was `return` that didnt work as you expected, next time it will be worse. Its too easy to write code that looks ok, compiles ok, tests ok, but has undefined behavior and will make demons fly out of your nose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` returns from a function. Hence, you cannot simply copy the code in the function to replace its call and expect the code to behave the same. The `return 0;` which before returned from `exit_c` now returns from `main`. Thats the difference you see.

On a related note: `return 0;` in `main` is implicit. You can remove it from your code when it is the last statement.